# How to swap second element of first row and penultimate element of last row from a matrix Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Description: a square matrix of dimension N is given. Write two implementations of solving an individual task:

1. based on the execution of subtasks in separate processes - for N iterations in the rows of the matrix;
2. based on sequential programming in one process - for 2N iterations along the rows of the matrix. In both implementations, counters should not be used.

My individual task is swap second element of first row and penultimate element of last row.

I was able to go through the matrix and replace the first elements of the first and last row, but how to do this for the second element of the first row and the penultimate element of the last row - difficult for me.

Any help, even just thoughts on direction, would be greatly appreciated.

```
-module(mtr).
-export([main1/1, main2/1, swap1/1, swap2/1, mtr_gn1/1]).

%% ver.1
%% (N) -> NewMatrix
main1(N) ->
    timer:tc(mtr, swap1, [mtr_gn1(N)]).

swap1([[A|R1]|Rs]) ->
    Pid = self(),
    spawn(mtr1, ch, [Rs, A, Pid]),
    receive
        {z, Z} -> Z
    end,
    receive
        {list, L1} -> L1
    end,
    [[Z|R1]|L1].

%% ver.2
main2(N) ->
    timer:tc(mtr, swap2, [mtr_gn1(N)]).

swap2([[A|R1]|Rs]) ->
    [Z|_Rz] = lists:last(Rs),
    [[[Z|R1]]|ch2(Rs, A)].

ch2([[_Z|Rz]], A) ->
    [[A|Rz]];
ch2([R|Rs], A) ->
    [R|ch2(Rs, A)].

mtr_gn1(N) ->
    [lists:map(fun(X) -> X/100 end, lists:seq(1, N)) |
     [[R || R <- lists:seq(1, N)] || _K <- lists:seq(1, N-1)]].


-module(mtr1).
-export([ch/3]).

%% ver.1
ch(L, A, Pid) ->
    Pid ! {list, ch1(L, A, Pid)}.

ch1([[Z|Rz]], A, Pid) ->
    Pid ! {z, Z},
    [[A|Rz]];
ch1([X|L], A, Pid) ->
    [X|ch1(L, A, Pid)].
```

Comment: Not the full solution but you should check if pattern-matching on 2 elements (i.e. `[ First, Second | Rest ] = AList`) and/or using [`lists:split/2`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#split-2) is enough to solve your issue.

Comment: Similarly, for the penultimate element: `[Pen, Last | []]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it`s impossible for N iterations, so I did it like that for N+1 iterations in separate processes (it was main task):

module 1:

```
-module(mtr).
-export([main1/1, main2/1, swap1/1, swap2/1, mtr_gn1/1]).

mtr_gn1(N) ->
    [lists:map(fun(X) -> X/100 end, lists:seq(1, N)) |
    [ [R||R <- lists:seq(1, N)] || _K<- lists:seq(1,N-1)]].

main1(N) -> 
    timer:tc(mtr, swap1, [mtr_gn1(N)]).

swap1([[A, B|R1]|Rs]) -> 
    Pid = self(),
    spawn(mtr1, ch, [Rs,B,Pid]),
    receive
    {z, Z} -> Z
    end, receive
    {list, L1} -> L1 end,
    [[A,Z|R1]|L1].


main2(N) -> 
    timer:tc(mtr, swap2, [mtr_gn1(N)]).

swap2([[A, B |R1]|Rs]) -> 
    [_Z, P|_Rz] = lists:reverse(lists:last(Rs)), 
    [[A, P|R1]|ch2(Rs,B)].

ch2([[Z|Rz]],A) ->
    [swap_penultimate([Z|Rz], A, [])];

ch2([R|Rs],A) ->
    [R|ch2(Rs,A)].

swap_penultimate([_Z,Y], A, Acc) -> 
    Acc ++ [A, Y];
    
swap_penultimate([H|T], A, Acc) ->
    swap_penultimate(T, A, Acc ++ [H]).
```

module 2:

```
-module(mtr1). 
-export([ch/3]).

ch(L,A,Pid) ->
    Pid ! {list, ch1(L,A,Pid)}. 

ch1([[Z | Rz]], A, Pid) -> 
    [swap_penultimate([Z | Rz], A, Pid, [])];

ch1([X|L],A,Pid) ->
    [X|ch1(L,A,Pid)].

swap_penultimate([Z,Y], A, Pid, Acc) -> 
    Pid ! {z, Z},
    Acc ++ [A, Y];

swap_penultimate([H|T], A, Pid, Acc) ->
    swap_penultimate(T, A, Pid, Acc ++ [H]).
```